# How can I return validation errors for objects created after_save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ice-cube

I'm writing a booking system which handles recurring bookings using the [ice_cube](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube) gem. A `Booking` has_many `BookingItem`s, one for each occurrence in the recurrence rule, and these are created in a method which is called by `Booking`'s after_save callback.

This was all working fine until I added a validation to `BookingItem` which avoids double booking by checking that there isn't already a `BookingItem` at the given time. This validation raises an error which I'd like to display on the booking form but at the moment it just silently prevents the `Booking` from being saved - since the error is raised by the `BookingItem` it's not being passed back to the form for the `Booking`.

app/models/booking.rb

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  include IceCube

  has_many :booking_items, :dependent => :destroy

  after_save :recreate_booking_items!

  # snip

  private

  def recreate_booking_items!
    schedule.all_occurrences.each do |date|
      booking_items.create!(space: self.requested_space, 
                            booking_date: date.to_date,
                            start_time: Time.parse("#{date.to_date.to_default_s} #{self.start_time.strftime('%H:%M:00')}"),
                            end_time: Time.parse("#{date.to_date.to_default_s} #{self.end_time.strftime('%H:%M:00')}"))
    end
  end
end
```

app/models/booking_item.rb

```
class BookingItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :booking

  validate :availability_of_space

  # snip

  private

    def availability_of_space
      unless space.available_between? DateTime.parse("#{booking_date}##{start_time}"), DateTime.parse("#{booking_date}##{end_time}")
        errors[:base] << "The selected space is not available between those times."
      end
    end
end
```

app/views/booking/_form.html.erb

```
<% if @booking.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <p><%= pluralize(@booking.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this booking from being saved:</p>
    <ul>
      <% @booking.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= form_for(@booking, :html => { :class => "nice custom"}) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: How are you currently trying to display the errors (what's your form code)?

Comment: I've added the relevant bit of form code. I suppose what I really need is some way of adding the `BookingItem`s' errors to `@booking`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your options are somewhat limited if you use an `after_save` callback to create the `BookingItem` objects.

Instead of using `after_save`, I would use `before_validation` and make a few adjustments to accommodate that.

1) Build the `BookingItem` objects in a `before_validation` callback

```
before_validation :recreate_booking_items!
```

and

```
def recreate_booking_items!
  schedule.all_occurrences.each do |date|
    booking_items.build(......
  end
end
```

Note that I'm using `build` instead of `create!`

When you validate the `Booking` object, the new `BookingItem` objects in the `booking_items` collection will be validated too.  Any errors will be included in the main `Booking` object's error collection, and you can display them in your view as you normally would because the `Booking` object will fail to save.

Notes

1) The `BookingItem` objects are validated automatically when the `Booking` object is validated because they are new records and belong to a `has_many` association.  They would not be automatically validated if they were persisted (i.e. already in the database).

2) `before_validation` callbacks can be called more than once in the lifecycle of an object, depending on your code.  In such a case, the `BookingItem` objects would be built each time the callback is called, which would result in duplicates. To prevent that, you can add the following line at the beginning of `recreate_booking_items!`:

```
booking_items.delete_all
```

Of course, you might not want to do that if you have persisted `BookingItem` objects in the database (see below).

3) This code is designed explicitly for creating `Booking` objects. If you are editing existing `Booking` objects that already have persisted `BookingItem` objects, certain modifications may be necessary, depending on your desired functionality.

UPDATE:

To address @Simon's follow up questions in the comments below.

I can think of two ways you might want do to this:

1) Keep the validation in `BookingItem` as you have it.

Then, I would have a custom validator in `Booking` like this:

```
validate :validate_booking_items

def validate_booking_items
  booking_items.each do |bi|
    if bi.invalid?
      errors[:base] << "Booking item #{bi.<some property>} is invalid for <some reason>"
    end
  end
end
```

This puts a nice custom message in `Booking` for each invalid `BookingItem`, but it also gives each `BookingItem` its own error collection that you can use to identify which `booking_items` are invalid.  You can reference the invalid `booking_items` like this:

@booking.booking_items.select {|bi| bi.errors.present?}

Then if you want to display the invalid `booking_items` in your view:

```
f.fields_for :booking_items, f.object.booking_items.select {|bi| bi.errors.present? } do |bi|
end
```

The problem with this approach is that a `BookingItem` may be invalid for several reasons, and trying to add all of those reasons into the base `Booking` error collection could get messy.

Therefore, another approach:

2) Forget the custom validator in `Booking`.  Rely on Rails' automatic validation of non-persisted members of a `has_many` collection to run the validation check for each `BookingItem` object.  This will give each one of them an errors collection.

Then, in your view you can loop through the invalid `booking_items` and display their individual errors.

```
<ul>
  <% @booking.booking_items.select {|bi| bi.errors.present? }.each do |bi| %>
    <li>
      Booking item <%= bi.name %> could not be saved because:
      <ul>
        <% bi.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul> 
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

If you use this approach, you will have the generic "Booking items is invalid" errors in your `Booking` object error collection, so you'll probably want to ignore those somehow so they don't display.

Note: I'm not familiar with IceCube, but if you're displaying `BookingItem` objects in the form via `nested_attributes_for`, that might clash with building the `BookingItem` objects in a `before_validation` callback.

Comment: This has almost done it, thanks. I've never paid that much attention to the `build` method before :) The problem now is that instead of showing the validation errors on the form, it just displays "Booking items is invalid" for each of the clashing recurrences and not the error that I've written in the `BookingItem` validation. Any idea how I can have this message displayed on the form instead? Ultimately the goal is to allow the user to select a different time or venue for each clashing recurrence.

Comment: @simon: You can put a custom validator in the `Booking` object that loops through the `booking_items` checking them for schedule clashes.  Then you can add whatever error message you want to the `Booking` object, and you can even specify which particular `BookingItem` is causing the problem, including the time slot, for example.  If you do this, you probably want to turn off the existing automatic validation of the associated `BookingItem` objects so that you don't get the generic error you're already getting in addition to the specific error.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Moving the validation to `Booking` has done the trick and I now have errors along the lines of "The Swimming Pool is not available between 08:45 and 11:45 on Sunday 10 June, 2012." which is much more helpful (and grammatically correct) than "Booking items is invalid". If you could give me a pointer on how to make an array of `BookingItem` objects with errors available to the form view then I'd be most grateful. Right now I've got `f.fields_for :booking_items` but that returns all of them :/

Comment: @Simon: I updated my answer to respond to your question about detecting the `booking_items` that are invalid.

Comment: This was a great help, thanks again for your detailed response :)